# ColdFusion Event Gateways in Clusters

Tags: events, coldfusion, cluster-computing

When clustering instances of Coldfusion, how do the event gateways respond? Do the requests also get distributed among the clutster? Or is it per instance?

Thanks,
Faisal Abid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible.

We wanted to use some event gateways across a load-balanced cluster and it wasn't possible. We ended up having to set up a server under a sub-domain for these kind of requests. We had the same problem with BlazeDS. If anyone knows of a way I'd love to hear it, but until I hear/read something I think the answer is no, without writing something custom to propagate the event yourself across the other machines in the cluster.